# Clarification for app to run in background using Service

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an app that should run in the background. I want my app to pop-up a message everyday at a particular time of day. As i read i will have to use 'Service' for this. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ProcessLifecycle   This link shows an example. But where should my code for pop-up be? I dint understand well from the above link. Another question i have is will the app continue to run even after a reboot?

Answer (score 0):

you can show a notification from the app to show pop up msgs, that is the best practice. though showing dialog is also possible. code will be in service only. see [this link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html) 

And to keep your application running after reboot you will have to register for BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast and whenever you receive that broadcast, you will have to launch your service again. see [this link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html)